# Nginx not caching static assets in reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I am trying to implement proxy_cache on top of node(express) server and want to cache responses.

The below code does a good job of caching api's, but it doesn't cache static assets.

The static assets are served from the downstream services (microservices), so the `public` folder here that I have mentioned is just for a POC (using `express.static` module).

How to cache static assets as well in nginx?

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    location / {
        proxy_cache mycache;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_valid 60m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache keys_zone=mycache:10m levels=1:2 max_size=100m inactive=60m;
```

Node Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')

app.enable('trust proxy')
app.use(morgan("short"))
app.use(express.static('src/public'))

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.json({
        message: 'ok'
    })
})

app.listen(8085)
```

Comment: It's a bit of a wild guess, but when you're proxying, the request doesn't reference the upstream server (node)'s filenames. Can you set up reverse-proxy headers and give it a try again? It should look something like the following:

https://gist.github.com/kuleszaj/1911022

Comment: Have already tried it (before posting question), doesn't work. I don't understand how setting up headers would be a problem, having said that it is only for static assets.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this easily with the following Nginx config.

**Nginx Config**

```
server {
 listen       80;
 listen       [::]:80;
 server_name  my-site.com;
 location / {
    proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
 }

 location /public {
    root /PATH_TO_YOUR_NODE_APP_PUBLIC_DIRECTORY
    expires 30d;
 }
}
```

In your express app .html files access these static files with /public prefix. Example: 'http://sample.com/public/app.css'

Comment: This is not I want, I would get the static files from some downstream services (microservices) and not from a folder. This solution is not for my use-case. The public directory that I had included is just for the poc. Sorry if I hadn't mentioned in the question earlier, will do it now.

Comment: Is it so. Let me change the answer for you.